# CMake : Linking cURL to my project : "cannot find -lcurl"

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, mingw, clion

I would like to use cURL with my project. I added this to my CMakelist :

```
include_directories(include)
link_directories(lib)
target_link_libraries(untitled curl)
```

This is the tree of my project :

[image: CLion file tree]

When I compile (with MinGW), I get this error :

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think curl is not properly linked, bt I don't know what I missed...

Comment: You have to tell CMake where cURL using "find" commands. How to use external libraries can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909627/2799037

Comment: @usr1234567 Thank you, it was very helpful ! I wrote these lines to my CMakelist : `find_library(CURL_LIB curl)` ; `target_link_libraries(untitled "${CURL_LIB}")` and `target_include_directories(untitled PUBLIC include)`, but now I have a lot of "undefined reference". Is my CMakeList right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this three lines after installing libcurl on your computer and everything will be ok.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lcurl")

add_executable(exec_name tests-main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exec_name curl)
```